# пространства имен php 7.3

Tags: php

У меня в пространстве имен `Test`, есть класс `A`.

При реализации нового класса `В` в этом же пространстве имени, мне не обязательно писать `use Test;`, чтобы иметь доступ к классу `A`?

Можно сразу так: ?

```
namespace Test;

class B {
   public function A() { return new A(); }
}
```

На практике это работает. Но можно ли так делать, и не будут ли ошибки в будущем ?

Также, если вышенаписанное правда, то как быть, если в классе `B` нужно будет юзать класс `C` из пространства имен `Test\SubTest` ?

Нужно полностью писать `use Test\SubTest;`
или можно сокращенно `use SubTest;`

?

Comment: По первому вопросу - да, можно не писать пространство имен для класса B если он в той же области что и A.
По второму вопросу - нужно указать полный путь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указывая `namespace Test;` вы обозначаете что находитесь в пространстве имен Test. Поэтому вам не нужно его использовать (указывать с помощью оператора `use`) ведь вы уже в нем.

По поводу второго вопроса. Использую оператор `use` вам нужно указывать абсолютный путь пространства имен. То есть `use Test\SubTest;`. Если же не использовать опертор use вы можете прямо в коде использовать относительный путь. Например `new SubTest\C;`. Что будет равносильно `new Test\SubTest\С;` если вы находитесь в пространстве имен Test.

Вы можете подробнее почитать про использование пространства имен здесь: 
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

Comment: спасибо, целую в десна